# Scrape all list <li> items in an <ul> using node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am trying to get all the contents in lists that have a similar class attribute. I want to use cheerio, requests and jquery to do so.

The list elements are of the form:

```
<a href="/anime/12-oz-mouse" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">12 oz. Mouse</a>
```

So I'm trying to use **a.ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r** to select all the elements and print them. I'm not seeing any results when I run the below, any thoughts as to how I can display all of the list elements; I specifically want the names of the cartoons [here](http://m.watchcartoononline.com/cartoon-list).

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('http://m.watchcartoononline.com/cartoon-list', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('a.ui-btn.ui-btn-icon-right.ui-icon-carat-r').each(function(i,e){
        console.log("cartoon " + $(this).text());
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you really assigning the results of the cheerio `load` to the jQuery variable `$`?

Comment: @jasonscript that is the suggested method in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, those classes are added using script after the page is loaded, so the page source don't have those classes.

What you can try is

```
request('http://m.watchcartoononline.com/cartoon-list', function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('ul[data-role="listview"] > li > a[href]').each(function(i,e){
        console.log("cartoon " + $(this).text());
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue I was having.